# CWE-749: Exposed Dangerous Method or Function Veracode issue while configuring the Spring Boot Admin Actuator endpoints

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin, veracode

I am trying to configure the SB admin in my Spring Boot application and trying to use the actuator endpoints.

My SB application: 2.1.5.RELEASE

For Admin,
 I have added below dependencies:

```
spring-boot-admin-starter-server -> 2.2.1
spring-boot-admin-starter-client ->2.1.1
```

The application.properties configured as follows:

[image]

So far everything is fine, I can able to access all features SB Admin, like logging, health.. etc.

But when I execute the Veracode scan I am ended up with below error.
The error was showing at this property (management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*).

[image]

The Veracode documentation described the link as follows: 
https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/749.html

My workaround: As it was talking about 'Exposed Dangerous Method or Function' I thought of applying the spring basic security so that Spring Boot admin console can't be accessed by unauthorized users.
 However, my problem didn't resolve. After a lot of research, I came to know that declaring 'management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*' itself is vulnerable? 
That is my guess, in this case, how can I solve this Veracode issue?

Comment: OK, I'm less inclined to want to help when I see pictures of code (in fact, I won't even click on the images you link and I suspect most others here won't either - which is kind of the point). Please post code snippets, or logs as text directly. Screenshots would serve no purpose for the problem you describe.

Comment: Did you find any solution?